# awk to print header and lines matching specific criteria

Tags: bash, perl, shell, awk, sed

I am printing `iostat` or similar output for instance:

```
[/] # iostat -xnCT d 5 5
Tue Nov 25 13:45:56 2014
                    extended device statistics
    r/s    w/s   kr/s   kw/s wait actv wsvc_t asvc_t  %w  %b device
    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0    3.1   0   0 c0
    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0    3.1   0   0 c0t0d0
    0.1    2.7    1.6    4.8  0.0  0.0    0.1    433.2   0   0 c1
    0.1    2.7    1.5    4.8  0.0  0.0    0.1    3.3   0   0 c1t0d0
    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0    100.1   0   0 c1t1d0
    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0    0.0   0   0 c1t2d0
    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0    0.5   0   0 c1t3d0
    0.1    0.1    0.1    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0    600.0   0   0 c2
    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    185.0    0.0   0   0 c2t0d0
    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0    0.0   0   0 c2t1d0
    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0    0.1   0   0 c2t4d0
    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    295.0    0.0   0   0 c2t5d0
    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0    0.1   0   0 c2t6d0
    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0    0.0   0   0 c2t8d0
    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0    0.0   0   0 c2t9d0
    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0    0.0   0   0 c2t10d0
    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0    0.1   0   0 c2t11d0
    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0    0.0   0   0 c2t12d0
    0.1    0.1    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0    0.0   0   0 c3
    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0    0.0   0   0 c3t0d0
    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0    0.0   0   0 c3t1d0
    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0    0.0   0   0 c3t2d0
    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0    0.0   0   0 c3t3d0
    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0    0.0   0   0 c3t4d0
    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0    0.0   0   0 c3t5d0
    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0    0.0   0   0 c3t6d0
    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0    0.0   0   0 c3t8d0
```

I generate these logs and then I use scripts to print out information. Now I am looking into some performance scripts where I need to for instance, grep for values that have high average service times from the log files which are generated all the time and see for instance values greater than 100.

So here is what I can do:

```
awk '$7 > 100 || $8 > 100' filename
```

So I will get all entries which have values of the wsvc_t and asvc_t greater than 100. Note, this is just an example. However, I also want to print the Date when this occurred, which cannot be done using grep -B or I am not sure how to use sed or awk to do this since the number of lines before the entry is not going to be a fixed one.

So is there an easy way to do this where I can print the lines with the values greater than 100 for $7 or $8 and then print the line which has 2014 or the year in it above the entry found?

So my result should be something like:

```
Tue Nov 25 13:45:56 2014
                    extended device statistics
    r/s    w/s   kr/s   kw/s wait actv wsvc_t asvc_t  %w  %b device
    0.1    2.7    1.6    4.8  0.0  0.0    0.1    433.2   0   0 c1
    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0    100.1   0   0 c1t1d0
    0.1    0.1    0.1    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0    600.0   0   0 c2
    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    185.0    0.0   0   0 c2t0d0
    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    295.0    0.0   0   0 c2t5d0
```

The log files will be running in thousands of lines.

Comment: For this input, `awk 'NR<=3 || $7 > 100 || $8 > 100' file` would make it. This would print the 3 first lines and then those matching your condition.

Comment: And if multiple dates can be in a file and you need to catch the extra date headers `awk 'NF < 7 || $7 > 100 || $8 > 100' file` would do that.

Comment: @EtanReisner That won't print the column headers though will it(i have not actually tried it).Tried it now, why is "wsvc_t" more than 100 haha.Actually why do it always equate to true no matter what number is used ?

Comment: @Jidder True. I wasn't considering that line. That it works coincidentally is amusing (string comparison is fun). Adding something to test for that line explicitly is easy enough to do in any number of ways though.

Comment: @EtanReisner interesting! See: `awk 'BEGIN {if ("a">100) print "yes"}'` returns "yes".

Comment: @fedorqui Yeah, string comparison (which is what awk is doing there, at least for gawk) is comparing character values and the digits are all less than the letters. Punctuation is more fun because some of it is "greater than" the numbers and some are "less than" the numbers.

Comment: @fedorqui : Please make it an answer.

Comment: @SkippyleGrandGourou I just did!

Answer (score 2):

I would use the following:

```
awk 'NR<=3 || $7 > 100 || $8 > 100'
```

This will print lines matching either of these conditions:

- `NR<=3`. `NR` stands for Number of Record, which in general is number of line. Thus, we are looking for the line number to be lower or equal to 3 (to print the header).
- 7th field strictly bigger than 100. This is what you already had.
- 8th field strictly bigger than 100. This is what you already had.

So the only thing I added to your current script is the `NR<=3`, which is quite useful when know exactly the line number we want to print, like now.

#### Test

With your given input stored as a file:

```
$ awk 'NR<=3 || $7 > 100 || $8 > 100' file
Tue Nov 25 13:45:56 2014
                    extended device statistics
    r/s    w/s   kr/s   kw/s wait actv wsvc_t asvc_t  %w  %b device
    0.1    2.7    1.6    4.8  0.0  0.0    0.1    433.2   0   0 c1
    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0    100.1   0   0 c1t1d0
    0.1    0.1    0.1    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0    600.0   0   0 c2
    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    185.0    0.0   0   0 c2t0d0
    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    295.0    0.0   0   0 c2t5d0
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to capture the interesting header data into variables as they pass by. Then, you need to choose to print the headers once when a bunch of interesting lines are seen. Finally, you need to reset the fact that the headers have been printed each time a new date is seen.

What is your preferred language? I'm not up-to-date on awk's current capabilities regarding patterns; I stopped caring when I started using Perl. So here's some Perl code I've banged up without testing:

```
source-process-feeding-lines | perl -n -e '
    if(/^(\w+ \w+ \d+ \d+:\d+:\d+ \d+)$/) {
        $date = $1;
        $header1 = $header2 = $printed = undef;    # reset heading state
        continue;    # next line please
    }

    if(/extended device statistics/) {
        $header1 = $_;
        continue;
    }

    if(/^(\s*\w\/\w.*device)$/ {   # simple but probably sufficient recogniser
        $header2 = $_;
        continue;
    }

    # assume a data line here
    if(/your pattern for an interesting line/) {
        if(! $printed) {
            $printed = 1;     # prevent a 2nd printing unless the date changes
            print $date, $header1, $header2;
        }

        print;    # print your interesting line
    }
'
```

This is close enough to what I think you're asking. Debugging probably needs applying!